NLA settings, or why isn't an action being executed?
As part of a multi-scene short film project (using Blender 4.2.1), I have a (Rigify rigged) character that does a named action which has been pushed on to the NLA stack (in fact, multiple versions of it have been pushed on to the stack). Everything was going fine until, at some point, I decided to edit the action and add some more keyframes to it. This I did, and then pushed the edited version on to the NLA stack for the character's armature. To be honest, I can't remember if I loaded the action into the action editor and then pushed it on to the NLA, or whether I merely selected the most recent, top-most version and edited it while in "tweak mode". In either case, immediately afterward Blender stopped executing the action, I cannot figure out why, and am at a complete standstill.
If I select the action from the topmost strip and hit tab to go in to tweak mode, I can see all the keyframes:

However, whether I tab out of editing mode or merely hit "x" in the action editor, or open it in the action editor and then push it down again, the result is the same, namely that none of the NLA strips for the armature are executed. When not editing the action (which is named 'Glinda Rig Action'), it looks like the top action should be executed. Yet when I scrub through the timeline, nothing.
In the outliner, I can see the multiple versions of 'Glinda Rig Action' that are stored in the NLA.

Is there a setting which I've accidentally toggled? Is this a bug?
I have made a stripped down blend file version which contains just the character armature, one scene, and the action strips I've shown in the images above. If anyone is will to take a look at it...thank you! Triple thanks if you fine a solution!
Stripped down blender file containing the rig and action strip which won't execute.(previous link was restricted--this one should be good). (88.5 Mb)
Thanks
RonE

hello, your link asks for an authorization   ;)

I'm not sure what you mean, it seems to work fine, she moves her arms and everything...

I'm embarrassed to say it, but it now works for me as well! I promise I'm not (too) crazy! The only difference between yesterday and today is that I closed and restarted Blender before loading the file, as opposed to switching files without first exiting from Blender.. I guess I'd assumed that when a new blend file is loaded, that everything inside Blender would be reset to it's default state, or rather to the state specified in the newly opened blend file. Could be a garbage collection issue. Thank you @moonboots for looking in iit.

The solution appears to be that Blender needed to be restarted!

OK, great then............   ;)
